# MS Access - SetFocus on multiple text boxes to check if data exists via SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, if-statement

The problem I'm facing:

I try to check if inserted text from multiple text boxes is already existing in a table before saving the records to avoid duplicates.

I created a form to enter new members and save them into a table. The key to avoid duplicates is to check the combination of given name, last name and birth date with existing records. (It's most likely that there won't be two person with all three criteria matching)

I have no problem to check the existence for only one text box by setting the focus on the desired box and use the SQL query IF EXISTS...

But since I would need to set focus on several text boxes(IMO) the problem occurs.
Is there a way to set focus on multiple text boxes?

The idea would be to use an IF EXISTS...AND EXISTS statement and I would need to implement the .SetFocus statement for each text box before checking its existence.

I hope you get my point and I would be glad if someone could share some knowledge. :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best thing here would be to tie a query to a button click event that would  then run a query using DoCmd.OpenQuery the query would check the combination of the fields, then generate a response if a match is found from what the user has entered

Comment: so you query could be something like select * from users where forename, surname, dob = (input taken from text box) - also at DB level there should be a compund key applied to the combination of these fields which means that this combination would be unique and can only be recorded once at table level

Comment: bearing in mind that john smith 01-01-2007 would be different to John Smith 2007/01/01 - some consideration over datatypes, and collation etc will need to be thought through so input validation becomes easier to manage.

Comment: please also consider that the combination of these 3 fields will not be unique in all cases, so I would have extended these fields to include some other information, perhaps some other demographics such as address and postcode, this then starts to make records for users a bit more unique, but you also need to think about how the slowly changing dimension would be handled, i.e. users that have changed address

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
Yes, I have already a button click event which starts the query.
There is no actual combination of the three fields, I'd like to check text box 1 against table field 1, text box 2 against table field 2...

And perform this with one query.

Comment: but if you are to check each of these fileds it can only be as single entities or the combination, you need to test the latter i.e. the combination of the first name, surname, dob which would be in the and statement in the query, checking individual fields against the query would be using or which would only test the valididty on a single column in the table - so query would be something like - select * from members where [first name] = input!forms!form1!fname AND [Surname] = input!forms!form1!sname AND [dob] = input!forms!form1!dob

Comment: You don't need `SetFocus` at all. Use `Form.Textbox.Value` instead of `.Text`.

Comment: Instead declaring and opening a recordset object, I would use DLookup().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some missing information in order to find the best solution to your problem. so the below response will be based on assumptions as to how your form is working.

I'm assuming you are using an unbound form with unbound text boxes? if this is the case, then you must have a button that is the trigger for checking/adding this information to your table. lets say your command button is called "Save". You can use the following code without the need to .setfocus to any textbox.

```
Private Sub Save_Click()
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL as string

set db = currentdb 'This is the connection to the current database

'This is the SQL string to query the data on your table

strsql = "SELECT * " & _
         "FROM [Yourtablename] " & _
         "WHERE ((([YourTableName].[FirstName]) ='" & me.FormFirstNameField & "' AND ([YourTableName].[LastName]) ='" & me.FormLastNameField & "' AND ([YourTableName].[DOB]) =#" & me.FormDOBField & "#));"
set rst = db.openrecordset(strsql) 'This opens the recordset
if rst.recordcount <> 0 then
    'Enter code to inform user information already exists
else
    'Enter code if information does not exits
end if

rst.close 'Closes the recordset
set rst = nothing 'Frees memory
set db = nothing 'Frees Memory
End Sub
```

Let me know if this code works or if I need to make changes based on your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately I get the error message "Run Time Error '3075' Syntax error (comma) in Query [...]

I tried Str() for the birthdate value but it didnt make a differnce. @Chris

Comment: sorry, brain fart. 

There shouldn't be commas in the query WHERE clause, the where clause should look as below:

"WHERE ((([YourTableName].[FirstName]) ='" & me.FormFirstNameField & "' AND ([YourTableName].[LastName]) ='" & me.FormLastNameField & "' AND ([YourTableName].[DOB]) =#" & me.FormDOBField & "#));"

Comment: I've also edited my original post in order to fit the comment above.